# Enable Display Format annotation from a ViewModel

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to develop an application using MVC 5 and EF 6 code first approach.

I am new at software devolpment.

I would like to add this data annotation:

```
 [DataType(DataType.Date)]
 [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

to a property named `Birthdate` from a ViewModels

An Example to illustrate:

```
public class StudentRegisterViewModel
    {
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
    }
```

The problem here is that the field `EnrollmentDate` does not recognize `DisplayFormat` annotations.
Can anyone help me, to handle it, please?

Answer (score 1):

The  `[DisplayFormat]` attribute is only used by DisplayFor and EditorFor. And not by the other helpers like TextBoxFor.

To format it further, you can create a css class and use jQuery to apply it:

```
$("EnrollmentDate").addClass("class-name")
```

Answer (score 1):

To apply the format specified in `[DisplayFormat]` you  need to access the value via `Html.DisplayFor()`. For example, in a view that would be:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(vm => vm.EnrollmentDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Write your own `ValidationAttribute`. To do this you override the `IsValid()` method with your own logic.

Add more validation if you wish:

```
public class MyAmazingValidationClass : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        DateTime date;
        bool parsed = DateTime.TryParse((string)value, out date);
        //or maybe : 
        bool parsed = DateTime.ParseExact((string)value),"dd/MM/yyyy")
        if(!parsed)
            return false;

        return true;
     }
}
```

Then go to your awesome class and decorate it:

```
public string FirstMidName { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[MyAmazingValidationClass(ErrorMessage="You made a big mistake right now!")]
public DateTime EnrollmentDate { get; set; }
```